# Как правильно загружать image в RecyclerView?

Tags: android, recyclerview, прокрутка, imageview

Ситуация следующая, есть `RecyclerView` он грузить данные из `sqlite` 80 записей, item выглядит так, слева изображение, в центре текст.
Проблема в том, что при быстрой прокрутке, `recycler` начинает жестко лагать.
Изначально думал что проблема в `setImageResource()`, так как читал где то, что этот метод лучше использовать при ленивых операциях. Заменил его на `setImageDrawable(drawable)`, вынес этот кусок кода в `Handler`

```
 int imageId = context.getResources().getIdentifier(item.getImageName(), "drawable", context.getPackageName());


            Drawable  drawable = context.getDrawable(imageId);

            holder.imageView.setImageDrawable(drawable);
```

ситуация не поменялась.
Изображения лежат в `drawable` в формате `VectorDrawable` и с размером 45dp x 45dp.
Как оптимизировать `recycler`, что бы не лагал при быстром скролле?

UPDATE:

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.ViewHolder> {

private Context context;
private List<Item> dataList;


public MyAdapter(Context context, List<Item> dataList) {

    this.context = context;
    this.dataList = dataList;

}

public class MyAdapter.ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    public TextView mTextView;
    public ImageView imageView;

    public ViewHolder(View view) {

    super(view);
    mTextView = view.findViewById(R.id.name_item);
    imageView = view.findViewById(R.id.image_item);

    }
}

@Override
public MyAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.my_item, parent, false);
    MyAdapter.ViewHoldervh = MyAdapter.ViewHolder(itemView);
    return vh;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final MyAdapter.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {

    final Item item = dataList.get(position);
    holder.mTextView.setText(item.getName());
    int imageId = context.getResources().getIdentifier(item.getimageId(), "drawable", context.getPackageName());
    Drawable drawable = context.getDrawableimageId
    holder.imageView.setImageDrawable(drawable);


}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return dataList.size();
}
```

}

Comment: код всего адаптера не помешает, гадать, чьо не так можно долго и безрезультатно

Comment: В адаптере все стандартно, не видел смысла выкладывать его.
TextView и ImageView во ViewHolder, и в onBindViewHolder устанавливаються значения.
Я скинул код установки изображения.
Код для TextView, textView.setText(item.getName);
Это все

Comment: возможно стоит попробовать glide или picasso

Comment: Пробовал picasso, увы тоже самое.

Comment: а у вас включен Instant Run? Если эта опция включена, то, даже не используя ее, это привдеет к лагам во всем приложении, в том числе в списках. Попробуйте отключить Instant Run и сравнить быстродействие

Comment: Да, включен, я про это совсем забыл. Попробую и отпишу о результате.

Comment: В общем отключил я Instant Run, тоже не помогло.
Я понял что дело в картинках, я убрал бинд картинок, оставил только текст в item, лаги пропали, возвращаю картинки, лаги появляются. Но все равно не понимаю что в картинках не так. картинки svg, маленький размер, непонятно.

Comment: Хотя я подозреваю, что проблема в viewportWidth="512" viewportHeight="512"` размере холста svg. Может ошибаюсь.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решил проблему. `Recycler` тормозил из-за сложных svg картинок, слишком много `path` было в них. Пришлось перейти на png с нарезкой под разные экраны.

Answer (score 0):

Рекомендую проверить, с помощью логов, переиспользуются ли у Вас **Holder**'ы. Возможно, при первом биндинге Вы используете цикл, в котором создаете новые **Holder**'ы.
Или, например,  у Вас **RecyclerView** находится внутри **ScrollView**.

Увы, без кода, действительно ничего не понятно. Ведь тут точно дело не в *методе присваивания*.

Comment: Выкинул код адаптера.
Recycler в ScrollView не находится

Answer (score 0):

Кэширование для recyclerView решает проблемы. Recycler выгружает память невидимых элементов, соттветственно загружает при появлении на экране. При кэшировании все итемы Recyclera будут в памяти, не стоит об этом забывать.

С параметрами нужно поиграться.

```
...
recyclerView.getRecycledViewPool().setMaxRecycledViews(0, 0);
recyclerView.setItemViewCacheSize(50);
recyclerView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
```